# How can I create a Makefile for C projects with SRC, OBJ, and BIN subdirectories?

Tags: c, makefile

A few months ago, I came up with the following generic `Makefile` for school assignments:

```
# ------------------------------------------------
# Generic Makefile
#
# Author: yanick.rochon@gmail.com
# Date  : 2010-11-05
#
# Changelog :
#   0.01 - first version
# ------------------------------------------------

# project name (generate executable with this name)
TARGET   = projectname

CC       = gcc -std=c99 -c
# compiling flags here
CFLAGS   = -Wall -I.

LINKER   = gcc -o
# linking flags here
LFLAGS   = -Wall

SOURCES  := $(wildcard *.c)
INCLUDES := $(wildcard *.h)
OBJECTS  := $(SOURCES:.c=*.o)
rm       = rm -f

$(TARGET): obj
    @$(LINKER) $(TARGET) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Linking complete!"

obj: $(SOURCES) $(INCLUDES)
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCES)
    @echo "Compilation complete!"

clean:
    @$(rm) $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Cleanup complete!"
```

This will basically compile every `.c` and `.h` file to generate `.o` files and the executable `projectname` all in the same folder.

Now, I'd like to push this a little. **How can I write a Makefile to compile a C project with the following directory structure?**

```
 ./
 ./Makefile
 ./src/*.c;*.h
 ./obj/*.o
 ./bin/<executable>
```

In other words, I'd like to have a Makefile that compiles C sources from `./src/` into `./obj/` and then link everything to create the executable in `./bin/`.

I've tried to read different Makefiles, but I simply can't make them work for the project structure above; instead, the project fails to compile with all sorts of errors. Sure, I could use full blown IDE (Monodevelop, Anjuta, etc.), but I honestly prefer to stick with gEdit and the good ol' terminal.

Is there a guru who can give me a working solution, or clear information about how this can be done? Thank you!

** **UPDATE (v4)** **

The final solution :

```
# ------------------------------------------------
# Generic Makefile
#
# Author: yanick.rochon@gmail.com
# Date  : 2011-08-10
#
# Changelog :
#   2010-11-05 - first version
#   2011-08-10 - added structure : sources, objects, binaries
#                thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/users/128940/beta
#   2017-04-24 - changed order of linker params
# ------------------------------------------------

# project name (generate executable with this name)
TARGET   = projectname

CC       = gcc
# compiling flags here
CFLAGS   = -std=c99 -Wall -I.

LINKER   = gcc
# linking flags here
LFLAGS   = -Wall -I. -lm

# change these to proper directories where each file should be
SRCDIR   = src
OBJDIR   = obj
BINDIR   = bin

SOURCES  := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)
INCLUDES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.h)
OBJECTS  := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
rm       = rm -f


$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @$(LINKER) $(OBJECTS) $(LFLAGS) -o $@
    @echo "Linking complete!"

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    @echo "Compiled "$<" successfully!"

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @$(rm) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Cleanup complete!"

.PHONY: remove
remove: clean
    @$(rm) $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)
    @echo "Executable removed!"
```

Comment: What is the specific question here?

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you want to do.

Comment: Updated the `Makefile`. I'm getting close, but I have trouble with the automatic variables, so it seems anyway

Comment: I just found a solution. If someone care to find something better, the Makefile can still be improved.

Comment: isn't it .PHONY instead of .PHONEY?

Comment: @joni it can be "BANANA" AFAIK.. besides, I'm not a native English speaker :)

Comment: @YanickRochon I didn't mean to criticize your English skills. But for the PHONY targets to make any sense you most definitely can't write BANANA ;) https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html

Answer (score 37, accepted):

First, your `$(OBJECTS)` rule is problematic, because:

1. it's kind of indiscriminate, making *all* sources prerequisites of every object,
2. it often uses *the wrong source* (as you discovered with `file1.o` and `file2.o`)
3. it tries to build executables instead of stopping at objects, and
4. the name of the target (`foo.o`) is not what the rule will actually produce (`obj/foo.o`).

I suggest the following:

```
OBJECTS  := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    @echo "Compiled "$<" successfully!"
```

The `$(TARGET)` rule has the same problem that the target name does not actually describe what the rule builds. For that reason, if you type `make` several times, Make will rebuild the target each time, even though there is no reason to. A small change fixes that:

```
$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(LINKER) $@ $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Linking complete!"
```

Once that's all in order, you might consider more sophisticated dependency handling; if you modify one of the header files, this makefile will not know which objects/executables must be rebuilt. But that can wait for another day.

**EDIT:**
Sorry, I omitted part of the `$(OBJECTS)` rule above; I've corrected it. (I wish I could use "strike" inside a code sample.)

Comment: with your suggested changes, I get : `obj/file1.o: In function 'main': \n main.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of 'main' \n obj/main.o:main.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here`

Comment: @Yanick Rochon: Do you have multiple `main` functions? Maybe one in `file1.c` and one in `main.c`? If so then you will not be able to link these objects; there can be only one `main` in an executable.

Comment: No, I do not. Everything works fine with the last version I posted in the question. When I change my Makefile to what you suggest (and I do understand the benefits of what you're saying) that's what I get. I just pasted `file1.c` but it gives the same message to every single files of the project. And `main.c` is the **only** one with a main function... and `main.c` imports `file1.h` and `file2.h` (there's no relation between `file1.c` and `file2.c`), but I doubt the problem comes from there.

Comment: @Yanick Rochon: I made a mistake pasting the first line of my `$(OBJECTS)` rule; I've edited it. With the bad line I got an error, but not the one you got...

Answer (score 7):

You can add the `-I` flag to the compiler flags (CFLAGS) to indicate where the compiler should look for source files , and the -o flag to indicate where the binary should be left:

```
CFLAGS   = -Wall -I./src
TARGETPATH = ./bin

$(TARGET): obj
    @$(LINKER) $(TARGETPATH)/$(TARGET) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Linking complete!"
```

In order to drop the object files into the `obj` directory, use the `-o` option when compiling. Also, look at the `$@` and `$<` [automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Automatic-Variables.html).

For example, consider this simple Makefile

```
CFLAGS= -g -Wall -O3                                                            
OBJDIR= ./obj

SRCS=$(wildcard *.c)
OBJS=$(SRCS:.c=.o )
all:$(OBJS)

%.o: %.c 
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $(OBJDIR)/$@
```

Update>

By looking at your makefile, I realize you are using the `-o` flag. Good. Continue using it, but add a target directory variable to indicate where the output file should be written.

Comment: could you be more specific? Do you mean adding `-l ...` to the `CFLAGS` and ... there's already the `-o` argument to the linker (`LINKER`)

Comment: Yes, the CFLAGS, and yes, keep using -o, just add the TARGETPATH variable.

Comment: Thank you, I have made the modifications, but it seems I'm still missing somethings (see the update on the question)

Comment: just `make`, from where the Makefile sits

Comment: Can't you read the command being executed? for example gcc -c yadayada. Pretty sure there's a variable that doesn't contain what you expect

Comment: @YanickRochon let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2302/discussion-between-tom-and-yanick-rochon)

Comment: Sorry Tom, I was somewhere else for a while, after yet another attempt. I went into the chat and saw your "No one there :(". Sorry

Comment: `%.o: %.c` rule is wrong. It does not produce the target it promises to produce. Should be `${OBJDIR}/%.o: %.c` and `-o $@`.

Answer (score -3):

I have stopped writing makefiles these days, if your intention is to learn go ahead, else you have  good makefile generator that comes with eclipse CDT. If you want some maintainability / multiple project support with in your build tree, have a look at the following -

https://github.com/dmoulding/boilermake I found this pretty good..!

Comment: Opinion based. Does not answer OP's question. Assumes Eclipse environment.