# Makefile C subdirectory rule to make obj

Tags: c, compilation, compiler-errors, makefile

I am running a simple Makefile with no problems:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -std=c99 -ggdb -Wall -I.
DEPS = hellomake.h
OBJ = hellomake.o hellofunc.o 

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

hellomake: $(OBJ)
    gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

The files are in the main project's directory:

```
./project/Makefile
./project/hellomake.c
./project/hellomake.h
```

Then I tried to organized the files, and put things like:

```
./project/Makefile
./project/src/hellomake.c
./project/include/hellomake.h
```

and extra subdirectories directories:

```
./project/lib
./project/obj
```

Then the new version of the Makefile:

```
IDIR =include
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -std=c99 -ggdb -Wall -I$(IDIR)

ODIR=obj
LDIR =lib

LIBS=-lm

_DEPS = hellomake.h
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

_OBJ = hellomake.o hellofunc.o 
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))


$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

hellomake: $(OBJ)
    gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~
```

I am compiling on Linux using Emacs with the gcc compiler:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
```

Then, I run on Emacs:

```
<Esc> 
x
compile
make
```

And it gives the message:

```
"./project/src/" -*-
make: *** No rule to make target `obj/hellomake.o', needed by `hellomake'.  Stop.
Compilation exited abnormally with code 2 at Wed Oct  3 17:10:01
```

What rule should be missing to be included in the Makefile file?

All comments and suggestions are highly appreciated.

---

Thanks for your suggestion, it is added to the code. Then the compiler complains:

```
make -k 
make: *** No rule to make target `src/hellomake.c', needed by `obj/hellomake.o'.
make: *** No rule to make target `../include/hellomake.h', needed by `obj/hellomake.o'.
make: Target `obj/hellomake.o' not remade because of errors
```

Some other suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `project/obj` would be a tad more sensible than `project/src/obj`

Comment: Hello Steve-o. Thanks! I made the change you suggested.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To fix the error `make: *** No rule to make target 'obj/hellomake.o', needed by 'hellomake'.  Stop.`

Change this line:

```
$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
```

To:

```
$(OBJ): $(ODIR)/%.o: src/%.c $(DEPS)
```

This creates a rule for all objects in the `$(OBJ)` variable.  The second parameter ('`$(ODIR)/%.o`') extracts the file name from the full path in order to pass just the file name to the third parameter ('`src/%.c`').

Comment: Hello Ryan. You are right.. the files were missing in the "src/". I also delete ".." as you suggested. But one error is left:
make: *** No rule to make target `/include/hellomake.h', needed by `obj/hellomake.o'.

Comment: Remove the beginning / from include.  That / tells the Makefile to look in the root directory of the filesystem instead of your project folder.

Comment: Ryan thanks again! I took off the "/". The one remaining error is gone. Then in (gdb) run  ... gives: {{ (gdb) run
Starting program:  
No executable file specified.
Use the "file" or "exec-file" command.}}

Comment: No problem!  I think you better make a new post about your gdb problem though.

Answer (score -1):

Ok. Now I am trying another example found here [ [How can I create a Makefile for C projects with SRC, OBJ, and BIN subdirectories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004702/how-can-i-create-a-makefile-for-c-projects-with-src-obj-and-bin-subdirectories) ] and here it goes:

```
TARGET   = hi.sh
CC       = gcc
# compiling flags here
CFLAGS   = -std=c99 -ggdb -Wall -I./src
TARGET   = bin/hi.sh

LINKER   = gcc -o
# linking flags here
LFLAGS   = -Wall -I. -lm

# change these to set the proper directories where each files shoould be
SRCDIR   = src
OBJDIR   = obj
BINDIR   = bin

SOURCES  := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)
INCLUDES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.h)
OBJECTS  := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
rm       = rm -f


$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @$(LINKER) $(TARGETPATH)/$(TARGET) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Linking complete!"

OBJECTS  := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    @echo "Compiled "$<" successfully!"

.PHONEY: clean
clean:
    @$(rm) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Cleanup complete!"

.PHONEY: remove
remove: clean
    @$(rm) $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)
    @echo "Executable removed!"
```

The files are organized as:

```
./project/bin/ executable
./project/ojb/*.0
./project/src/*.c and *.h
./project/Makefile
```

The compiler persists giving only one complaint:

```
make -k 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file /bin/hi.sh: Permission denied
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bin/bin/hi.sh] Error 1
```

Thanks a lot for all comments and suggestions!

Comment: Even if this is years old, your problem simply is that `TARGETPATH` is not defined and therefore `$(TARGETPATH)/$(TARGET)` in the linker will resolve to `/bin`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should change this line

```
$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
```

change to

```
$(ODIR)/%.o : %.c $(DEPS)
```

add a Space after %.o.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).