# Makefile, how to put OBJ files in separate directory?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Currently my project has all files within a single directory. I am trying to reorganize it such that I have a `src` directory for *.c files, an `include` directory for *.h files, and an `obj` directory for *.o files as a subdirectory of src. My makefile with every file in one directory works fine and looks like this:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I. -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror
DEPS = Triangle.h
OBJ = Trianglecalc.o Triangle.o
TESTOBJ = area_of_triangle_test.o verify_triangle_test.o validate_input_test.o get_side_length_test.o Triangle.o
LIBS=-lm

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

Trianglecalc: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

tests: $(TESTOBJ)
    $(CC) -o area_of_triangle_test area_of_triangle_test.o Triangle.o $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)
    $(CC) -o verify_triangle_test verify_triangle_test.o Triangle.o $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)
    $(CC) -o validate_input_test validate_input_test.o Triangle.o $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)
    $(CC) -o get_side_length_test get_side_length_test.o Triangle.o $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

test-all:
    ./area_of_triangle_test > test_log.txt
    ./verify_triangle_test >> test_log.txt
    ./validate_input_test >> test_log.txt
    ./get_side_length_test >> test_log.txt

.PHONY: clean

clean:
     rm *.o $(objects) Trianglecalc area_of_triangle_test verify_triangle_test validate_input_test get_side_length_test
```

I have been following this guide to create my makefile:
[A Simple Makefile Tutorial](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/)

Here is what my makefile looks like after reorganizing my project as described above. This makefile is within the `src` directory:

```
CC=gcc
IDIR=../include
CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR) -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror
ODIR=obj

_DEPS = Triangle.h
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

_OBJ = Trianglecalc.o Triangle.o
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

_TESTOBJ = area_of_triangle_test.o verify_triangle_test.o validate_input_test.o get_side_length_test.o Triangle.o
TESTOBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_TESTOBJ))

LIBS=-lm

$(OBJ): $(ODIR)/%o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

Trianglecalc: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

tests: $(TESTOBJ)
    $(CC) -o area_of_triangle_test area_of_triangle_test.o Triangle.o $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)
    $(CC) -o verify_triangle_test verify_triangle_test.o Triangle.o $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)
    $(CC) -o validate_input_test validate_input_test.o Triangle.o $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)
    $(CC) -o get_side_length_test get_side_length_test.o Triangle.o $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

test-all:
    ./area_of_triangle_test > test_log.txt
    ./verify_triangle_test >> test_log.txt
    ./validate_input_test >> test_log.txt
    ./get_side_length_test >> test_log.txt

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm *.o $(objects) Trianglecalc area_of_triangle_test verify_triangle_test validate_input_test get_side_length_test
```

Following the guide linked above I originally had `$(OBJ): $(ODIR)/%o: %.c $(DEPS)` as `$(ODIR)/%o: %.c $(DEPS)`, but then I got the error:

```
$ make
    make: *** No rule to make target 'obj/Trianglecalc.o', needed by 'Trianglecalc'. Stop.
```

I change the line to `$(OBJ): $(ODIR)/%o: %.c $(DEPS)` as suggested in this answer: [Makefile C subdirectory rule to make obj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711154/makefile-c-subdirectory-rule-to-make-obj)
but now I get:

```
$ make
    make: *** No rule to make target 'Trianglecalc..c', needed by 'obj/Trianglecalc.o'. Stop.
```

The previous post I linked suggests that this might be due to a spelling error, but I can't find it. I'm confused at how make ended up at `Trianglecalc..c` instead of `Trianglecalc.c`, the only place in the makefile with a `..` is as part of the `IDIR` variable. Any suggestions?

P.S. I haven't gotten around to updating the `tests:` and `clean:` rules but I'm sure that at least the `clean:` rule will need to be fixed. As best I can tell the current problem is with the `Trianglecalc:` rule.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to place object files in separate subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178125/how-to-place-object-files-in-separate-subdirectory)

Comment: You forgot one dot in your `$(OBJ):` rule. Replace `$(ODIR)/%o` by `$(ODIR)/%.o`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Thanks, that solved my problem!