# How Can I fix 'Makefile:6: *** missing separator. Stop'.?

Tags: makefile

```
all: elfparser

elfparser: disasm.o elf-parser.o elf-parser-main.o elf-program_read.o srec.o
    gcc -o elfparser disasm.o elf-parser.o elf-parser-main.o elf-program_read.o srec.o

elf-parser-main.o: elf-parser-main.c
    gcc -c -o elf-parser-main.o elf-parser-main.c

disasm.o: disasm.c
    gcc -c -o disasm.c

elf-parser.o: elf-parser.c
    gcc -c -o elf-parser.c

elf-program_read.o: elf-program_read.c
    gcc -c -o elf-program_read.c
    
srec.o: srec.c
    gcc -c -o srec.c

clean:
    rm -rf *o elfparser
```

Comment: `tab`s and `new lines` matter in a Makefile.  I will edit your question, also, your make file has other problems when generating .o files.

Comment: This can't be the identical makefile as the one where you got this error because there's no error on line 6 here, as the question title states.  However this error is the single most common problem people have writing makefiles: any search for this error message on the internets will give you lots of information about what's wrong...

Answer (score 0):

[This question is already VERY NICELY although slightly differently answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004702/how-can-i-create-a-makefile-for-c-projects-with-src-obj-and-bin-subdirectories)

Here is a slightly better approach:

```
BIN=elfparser
SRC=disasm.c elf-parser.c elf-parser-main.c elf-program_read.c srec.c

# OBJ filenames are created from SRC filenames by replacing .c with .o
OBJ=$(SRC:%.c=%.o)

CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-O2 -g

default: $(BIN)

# To create the binary, build all objects first
$(BIN): $(OBJ)
        $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJ) 

# How to generate a .o from a .c rule:
%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ -c %<
```

If you decide to cut and paste this code remember that the lines that are under the rules (i.e. commands that run in the shell to do the work) *HAVE TO HAVE A <TAB>* (not spaces) before them.

Comment: Thanks, Ahmed Masud